# Download Ubuntu Live CD

Tags: ubuntu, livecd

For pxe boot I need iso Ubuntu. The problem is when Clients requests iso from the Server and iso is Standard Desktop Image (around 1.5 GB), Clients just do not have enough RAM... So I need just Live CD with no option 'Install Ubuntu'

Is it possible to download only Live CD Image and if it is please share the link.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you check https://www.ubuntu.com/download ?

Comment: Of course! The first thing I did, but it seems like it is not there, or they named it differently

Comment: Are you assuming the LiveCD ISO size is smaller? It's not.

Comment: It should be, since I do not need option 'Install Ubuntu'

Answer (score 1):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD

> The standard Ubuntu Cd can be used as a LiveCd as well as an installer. Live mode is the default option when booting from CD. Only some of the non-standard downloads (such as the "Alternate Cd") lack this functionality.

Ubuntu recommends at least 2GB of RAM for the LiveCd, so maybe your client isn't up to par? Have you tried a lighter distro like [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) or [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)?

Another great option would be to [customize the standard Ubuntu ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization), removing some of the larger software packages like OpenOffice, GIMP, and Firefox. These are considerably larger than the install software.

Comment: I understand that Standard Ubuntu can be used this way. The problem is I neen boot Client through Server using PXE, and Standard Iso is 1.5 Gb, for Client's RAM is it way too much, so I need just Live CD with no option 'Install Ubuntu'

Comment: @John - Edited to provide some more useful options. I apologize for not understanding your original question.

Comment: You could also extract the FS and have it available via NFS so the clients don't need to hold it all in RAM.

Comment: ivanivan, how to do that? Can you please give me a guide link?